# Converting .MSG files to .TXT; Should I use Microsoft.Interop Outlook?

Tags: c#, text, outlook, interop, msg

I'm trying to do a conversion from .msg files into .txt.  I have two questions.

1)I've been investigating and found the Microsoft.Interop Outlook package and there is a way where I can extract the bodyHTML, To, Sent Date, and a few other properties but I feel as if this is a very manual process because I have to trim out all the html tags such as < br>, &nbsp, a href etc...

Here is my current code...

```
MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(item) as MailItem;
TextFile textFile = new TextFile(); //collection of properties I am interested in
textFile.To = mailItem.To;
textFile.Subject = mailItem.Subject;
textFile.Sent = mailItem.SentOn.ToString();
textFile.Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item);
var atttach = mailItem.Attachments;  //Really just want the names 
textFile.Body = RemoveStuff(mailItem.HTMLBody); //manually removing all html tags
textFiles.Add(textFile);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
```

Does anyone know if there is a more effective way to do this in C# or a way using Interop that I am not aware of?

2)If I go the interop route, is there a way I can bypass the popup in Outlook asking if I can allow access to Outlook?  Seems inefficient if my goal is to create a converter.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, why are you using `HTMLBody` property instead of the plain text Body?

Secondly, you can use `MailItem.SaveAs(..., olTxt`) to save the message as a text file. Or do you mean something else by txt file?

The security prompt is raised by Outlook if your antivirus app is not up to date. If you cannot control the environment where your code runs, Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or a wrapper like [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (any language - I am its author) are pretty much your only option. See  http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for more details.

In [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/), you can have something like the following:

```
using Redemption;
...
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
RDOMail msg = session.GetMessageFromMsgFile(TheFileName);
msg.SaveAs(TxtFileName, rdoSaveAsType.olTXT);
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, that's exactly what i needed to do, which was saving it as a text.  (I wasn't aware of the saveAs and that's why I was using the HTMLBody and manually parsing out all the html tags and entities). Only thing now is that it's not capturing the mailItem.To properties.  I've heard of Redemption, but won't be able to use it due to licensing. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Are you saying txt format does not save the To/CC headers? Or that the email addresses are not included?

Comment: Both, if i type in mailItem.To it's null, but in my .MSG there are clearly To recipients.  Since its null, there isn't anything being saved onto the text file.

Comment: Do you see the PR_DISPLAY_TO property for that message file if you open it in OutlookSpy (click OpenIMsgOnIStg)?

Comment: It says MAPI_E_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY but when i double click on the values, i see all the email addresses and names in there.

Comment: Hmm weird, I set my BodyFormat property to OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain and it worked.

Comment: Does this only happen on MSG files with large number of recipients?

Comment: Yes this only happens when the MSG file has a large number of recipients.

Comment: This is an OOM limitation. I can only suggest using Redemption (it does nto have this limitation) or Extended MAPI ( PR_DISPLAY_TO property needs to be opened as IStream rather than retrieved using IMAPIProp::GetProps)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I will look into that.